# Dynamically Instantiate ASP.NET page class object by virtual path

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, visual-studio-2010

Can this be done? And how?

I've Tried the following without success:

- **Method1** using `BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath` - doesn't work after publish. (I assume it fails because i use strong name assembly pre-compilation, not sure).
- **Method2** using the following code:

  ```
  Page page = new SchedulerTest();  // An ASPX Page class (note: CodeBehind) 
  page.AppRelativeVirtualPath =
  context.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath; 
  page.ProcessRequest(context);
  ```

  As found [here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Jul/23/Loading-an-ASPNET-Page-Class-dynamically-in-an-HttpHandler) - Won't work as I don't know the page class name
  at runtime.

Comment: +1 for interesting question/-1 for random link instead of explanation= 0. Please explain "Method2" in couple sentenses in addition to a link. Links can go dead and than the question (or answer) stops make not sense in a future.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is what I think.

a) Why don't you know the name of the class until runtime? How do you work out what the classname is going to be? If you can work out the relationship then you can use reflection to create an instance of the page and then use that.

b) What are you actually trying to achieve? If you are trying to route a request to another request based on some criteria (query string or something) then you can use an HttpModule and rewrite the path. I am struggling to see what else you might be trying to do. In this way you can use your virtual path again.

Comment: I'll try to explain my situation better: When error occurs, our system redirects to 'ErrorPage' with a query 'errouniousPage=~/path/PageErrorOccurredOn.aspx'. When i handle the request to 'ErrorPage' i want to get the 'PageErrorOccurredOn' object instance to check for what master page it uses.

Comment: Easiest way I can see to do it is to store information about the request as it happens. Then when the error occurs you can just pop the last information off - or whatever you are using. Use something like a shared baseclass and an oninit or load method to add into the session or somewhere. Can load whatever information you want - current relative url, master page, page name. Probably not what you were after in terms of 'nice' but .. it doesnt sound like its doing anything nice either way.